# How to override/disable ncurses input?

Tags: c++, qt, keypress, ncurses, keyevent

I'm writing a code, and I'd like to make it in two variants - with text-based interface (TUI) implemented with ncurses, and with GUI implemented with Qt5. So, passing an argument in the command-line, I can choose which version to run - with GUI or TUI (e.g., just like with YaST in openSUSE). The rest of the code, including inputs from the keyboard, should be independent of which interface (TUI or GUI) is chosen. As I see it, the optimal way to implement such a program is to use distinct classes for input, for user interface, etc. So, in whatever version I run the code, the class handling the input should be the same, and it passes the data to the interface class, which might be TUI or GUI, depending on how the application was launched. The problem is that for ncurses it seems impossible to detach input from the output. Basically, what I want is to still be able to use ncurses output (windows, panels, etc.), but to perform input with some other library. Anyone knows how to solve that? Also, what input C/C++ libraries can I use for reading keyboard event in whatever mode (terminal or GUI)?

Comment: I would suggest either having two builds for your program, one for gui and one for cli, or detecting the different situation, and handing the program to QT or command line as soon as possible. Trying to generalize this will probably be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: I wonder how this implemented in YaST (and other single-build apps which may run both with ncurses and GUI interfaces, depending on the situation). Do they have different input handlers for each interface?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that those applications are not a single executable, but the same source-code compiled with different options [for text and gui], and a wrapper shell-script (or binary) that decides which to use.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it would be a simple solution, but seems the other way round :) I'll pursue Phil's suggestion then.

Comment: XY problem. What does "detaching input from output" mean to you and how exactly ncurses hinders it? Please provide a code example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: To me it means that if initialize ncurses [initscr(), etc] and then begin the main input loop, where I read keys with ncurses function like getch(), everything is Ok. But if instead I use, e.g., std::cin.get(char), the program does not respond, no windows are drawn, etc.

Comment: What probably confuses you is that `getch` does a `refresh`, and your screen gets updated automatically.  If you use another input and omit the `refresh` calls, no screen updates happen.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for the hint. But now I wonder why ncurses uses its own input functions like wgetch, etc., if everything still might be handled with standadr C/C++ input functions? Is it only for convenience, or is there some fundamental difference?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use ncurses' input-functions (such as `wgetch`) when using ncurses for output.

A few programs do this ([Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/), [vi-like-Emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html)) because they use inputs that largely are *not* resolved to special keys using ncurses, such as

- the <kbd>escape</kbd> character by itself (vi-like-Emacs), or
- the mouse-code in Midnight Commmander (which uses `select` for monitoring multiple inputs).

Managing different *output* streams actually can be more difficult, since those use information about the appearance of your program on the computer screen.  Inputs usually do not occupy more than a line or so of the screen.

In vi-like-Emacs, the program uses a terminal-driver which knows how to work with a specific type of device (terminal emulator, X windows, Win32 GUI), and the program is compiled and linked with that driver.  It would be nice to be able to switch between drivers at runtime, but nuances of mouse-handling are harder to factor out than keyboard input and screen updates.